# Amount of numbers with certain condition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm sorry I have asked until now up to three questions regarding the same topic, but tomorrow I have a Combinatorics exam and I'm practising in order to be ready and do my best. Here is the question: I am requiered to find how many numbers in the set $\{1\dots 1000\}$ there are whose sum of digits is $5$. Here is my attempt:

I started separating in cases, depending on how many digits there were:

1. If we only have one digit, it is easy: only the number $5$ satisfies it: 1 option
2. If we have two digits, it is the same as solving $x_1 + x_2 = 5$, where $x_i$ is the $i$-digit and $x_1 \geq 1, x_2 \geq 0$. The number of solutions is, if I'm not wrong, ${5 \choose 1} = 5$
3. If we have three digits, the argument is the same as above, but with three variables: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 5, x_1 \geq 1, x_2,x_3 \geq 0$. The number of solutions is ${6 \choose 2} = 15$.
   Therefore, and since cases are mutually exclusive, the result would be the sum of these three options: $21$. Am I right?

Comment: Looks good. $\quad $

Comment: As a mechanical check, the direct count is pretty easy.  The only challenge is for the three digit numbers, but you only need to look at the numbers in  $\{104, 113, \cdots, 500\}$ and that's not that bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your argument works, but there's a more elegant solution!

Allow leading zeroes. Ignoring the number $1000$, whose digits don't sum to $5$ anyway, treat each number as a $3$-digit string $d_2d_1d_0$. So we're looking to enumerate integer solutions to $$
d_0 + d_1 + d_2 = 5, 
$$
where each $d_i \geq 0$. This is a stars-and-bars calculation:
$$
\binom{5+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{7}{2} = 21.
$$

Comment: I still cannot understand how I couldn't come up directly with that. Thanks for your answer